# php dom agregar un elemento html

Tags: php, html, dom

Tengo un documento HTML, con varias etiquetas `iframe` con una url de youtube

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx" width="560px"></iframe>
```

Usando PHP DOM, ¿cómo puedo remplazarlas por

```
    <figure>
       <iframe>
         <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx"></iframe>
      <iframe>
    </figure>
```

estoy usando este codigo php usando el dom pero no puedo agregar el iframe que me falta

```
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
    $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));
    $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
    $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
    $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
}
```

Me podrian ayudar porfavor, saludos

hola gracias por su respuesta, tengo un documento html donde tengo varios iframes que tiene un src a youtube pero tengo que agregar unas etiquetas html

`<figure><iframe><iframe src="xxx"></iframe><iframe></figure>`

para poder leerlo en otro sitio, con el codigo que puse solo logro que la salida sea asi

`<figure><iframe src="xxx"></iframe></figure>`

por lo que me falta un iframe

lo intente asi:

```
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
     $iframeMain = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));
    $iframeMain->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
    $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
    $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
    $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
}
```

pero se queda ciclado, si cambio:

```
$iframeMain = $doc->createElement('iframe');
```

por

```
$iframeMain = $doc->createElement('strong');
```

si lo imprime pero asi:

```
<figure><strong><iframe src="xxx"></iframe><strong></figure>
```

Comment: Deberías utilizar Javascript para realizar ese cambio, no PHP.

Comment: @Jemonge a lo mejor está construyendo un scraper

Comment: @amanadiel tienes razón pero el enunciado no lo menciona. Skycomputer2 podrías agregar más información sobre lo que buscas realizar para aclarar esta duda.

Comment: muchas gracias añadi los comentarios arriba saludos